# Grouping and displaying items of different types in a collection view - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a journal type gui, where entries are ordered by their date.
I want to fetch my journal entries from the datbase and group the ones that were added on the same day and separete these groups with a label.
Kind of like the facebook messenger chat history.

This is what I was thinking about:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding JournalEntries}" SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label>Date</Label>
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding}">

                    </CollectionView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
```

The problem is that 'JournalEntry' object can be of many types.
For example 'Photo' derives from  'JournalEntry'. So if a 'Photo' object is in the 'JournalEntries' collection I want the image to be displayed and not the 'ToString()' text.

1. **What would be he best way to group the JournalEntries  into different days, so I can display an label over the group?**
2. **How can I decide in runtime wether an object should be displayed as an image or as text?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are answers:-

1. You can use `JournalEntries.GroupBy(x=> x.date).ToDictionary()`. For this you will have to use System.Ling. This will return you a Dictionary, whose Key will be the Date and all the entries in a form of List in the Value. This will be easier for you to use.
2. You can use a DataTemplateSelector or Converter for choosing an option at runtime. With a DataTemplateSelector you will have to make two DataTemplates one for each Image and Text. For Converter you will have to toggle the visibility on the basis of the data which comes from the Server/Database.

Let me know for further queries. I can help you out for sure!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About point 1. - I'm still unsure how I can then make sure the date is printed only once for each day. With your solution I would still need to use a CollectionView inside another CollectionView right?

Comment: You can use Grouping in CollectionView. Nested CollectionView is not a good practise. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping. Link for your reference.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some research and some testing I have found a suitable solution for me. Nikhil's answer is correct, but I would say incomplete, specially as it pertains to the DataTemplateSelector part.

First I created a class called `EntryGroup` which derives from `List<Entry>`.
After this I created a Property for binding in my ViewModel called `Entries` which was an `IEnumerable` of type `EntryGroup`.
This process is outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping).

I created a GroupHeaderTemplate to display the dates.

In my ViewModel I get the entries from my repository and use the `.GroupBy(it => it.Timestamp.Date)` Linq method. This returns an `IGrouping<DateTime, Entry>`.
Since it already extends IEnumerable, half of the job is done.
I wrote them to the Entries IEnumerable using a foreach loop.

Then I create a class deriving from `DataTemplateSelector` and created an `ImageTemplate` and a `TextTemplate` as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector)